# usb debugging not connected to pc

Tags: android, usb

I have android device its `samsung galaxy GT-S5300` and version is *2.3.6*. I want to connect my device with computer for running the apps directly to device via eclipse.

I have installed the `samsung kies` on my system and i did the following setting on my phone but I **could not get connected with pc for debugging mode(Developing)**. **But the sd card is mounted to pc.**

1)Setting -> Application -> UnKnown sources ->enabled the option.

2)Setting -> Application -> Development-> USB debugging ->enabled the option. 
But still not connected my device with pc for debugging mode.

How to get connected the device with pc for USB debugging mode?

Comment: I think you could also follow this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey murali_ma,

```
             Do this...

1. Open command prompt and type adb kill-server
2. then again type adb start-server
3. then adb install path of apk
```

i am sure you will get the success.

Comment: hello murli_ma,  Simply install the apk through command prompt. if you success please like and upvoted it.

Comment: thanks its works, but i have a doubt that is , may i do the above process every time to install the same app or other app?please explain.

Comment: Yes, you can. Eclipse also follows the same process behind the scene.